# backticked argument seems to interpreted twice?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm not entirely sure how to categorize this question. It feels like I discovered a bug in `tail` and/or `bash`, but obviously it's much more likely this is a bug in my understanding!

I ran the following command:

```
tail -f -n`wc -l scrape.log` scrape.log
```

in order to `cat` the entire file and any new material that is added. However, this `tail`ed the file *twice*. Running this command:

```
tail -f -n`wc -l scrape.log`
```

gave me the desired outcome, `tail`ing the file once. I thought backticks are a Bash escape tool, to "preprocess" a command before running the next one. What is going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use backticks you're essentially passing the output of one command to another. Now let's see what `wc -l` does:

```
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ wc -l /etc/passwd
11 /etc/passwd
```

It outputs the number of lines **and the filename**. So your command becomes:

```
tail -f -n 11 scrape.log scrape.log
```

Comment: D'oh! This should have been obvious. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 4):

If your `tail` supports it, you can use

```
tail -f -n +1 scrape.log
```

to begin the `tail` with line 1 of the file.

(I am purposefully not answering your question, which cnicutar has already done. I'm just presenting a possible alternative.)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I missed this part of the `man` page, and it is a more straight-forward way of achieving my desired result.

Answer (score 1):

#### Alternative solution

```
tail -f -n $(wc -l < scrape.log) scrape.log
```

Input redirection prevents the printing of the file name.